Visual Studio 2022 blocking my PrintScreen key
I use Windows 10 and in the keyboard shortcut settings, I changed the standard screenshot call Win+Shift+S to just the PrintScreen key on my keyboard. It works well, but I noticed that when I press the Print Screen key in the Visual Studio window, there is no reaction. When I opened the clipboard, I found that Visual Studio intercepts the Print Screen key and takes a screenshot on its own, adding it to the clipboard.
My main question is how to disable the interception of some keys in Visual Studio (in my case, version 2022), since these keys are not available in the parameters.
In fact, I am not so worried about the inability to take a screenshot while in Visual Studio as the inability to call the hotkey of another utility (double Shift) to change the language I wrote to another language layout (the Caramba Switcher utility). As far as I remember, there were no such problems in Visual Studio 2019
I tried to change this in the Visual Studio keyboard settings or find on the Internet where the keyboard configuration file is located directly, but with no result

I've searched extensively and found no direct way to modify the interception. Typically, the application processes keyboard events internally. You could request the feature in the
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio.
.
